# Settings.bundle with separate options for a Mac Catalyst app?

Tags: ios, xcode, mac-catalyst

In an app originally built for iOS and iPadOS, it has a `Settings.bundle`, that contains `Root.plist` with settings for the iOS app, and `Root~ipad.plist` with settings for the iPadOS app. That's all good.

I'm adding a Mac Catalyst edition, and need to customize the settings for this edition. But adding a `Root~mac.plist` file is ignored, and other similar names. Is this supported, or an oversight?

I did figure out a way to accomplish this, using the Xcode project Build Phases and a copy of the Settings.bundle, with different filter criteria for each, but it would have been nice if I could use the same bundle like with iOS and iPadOS.

[image: Xcode Build Phases]

Comment: It might be helpful to update your question and show an example of what's different in your Root.plist between iPhone, iPad, and Mac.